# ¿Cómo guardar muchos datos en una relacion muchos a muchos? rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Buenas gente, estoy haciendo un sistema administrativo en rails 5, y voy por la parte de permisología, básicamente quiero que un usuario tenga muchos grupos, y muchos grupos tengan muchos usuarios, sé que es una relación has_many through, lo sé emparejar desde consola, pero solo sé tomar un usuario y un grupo, por ejemplo:

```
usuario = User.create name:"Luis", email:"example@email.com"
grupo = Group.create name:"Desarrollo", description:"Los que se joden gracias a los de diseño >:v"
grupo2 = Group.create name:"Diseño", description:"Los creativos"
grupo3 = Group.create name:"Ventas", description:"Los bichos fastidiosos que solo piensan en hacer dinero de la noche a la mañana"
membership = Membership.create group:grupo, user:usuario
```

Los controladores son scaffolds básicos sin ningún añadido, y los usuarios están registrados por medio de devise

Quiero que el administrador cuando cree un grupo administre sus usuarios y viceversa, que cuando cree un usuario administre sus grupos.

No quiero que un administrador tenga que ir marcando un grupo a la vez, sino que desde la vista seleccione varios grupos (desarrollo, diseño, reclutamiento), y que rails los guarde todos de una sola vez.
Ni tampoco que registe al mismo usuario varias veces con los diferentes grupos que puedan existir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con las vistas básicas de scaffold no lo vas a poder lograr. Tenés varias opciones para asignar masivamente hijos a un padre. Por ejemplo:

```
group = Group.first
group.user_ids = [1,2,6]
```

El formulario de la vista tiene que generar los parámetros de la siguiente forma:

```
 group: {id: 1, name: "Desarrollo", description: "Los que se joden gracias a los de diseño >:v", user_ids: [1,2,5]}
```

Para lograr esto, tenés que habilitar los parámetros en el controlador de la siguiente forma:

```
def groups_params
  params.require(:group).permit(id:, :name, :description, user_ids: [])
end
```

Lo mismo del lado de los usuarios.